# Laradock: multiple projects on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, laradock

I've installed Laradock but can not setup multiple projects on localhost for development.

1) Cloning Laradock git repo

`git clone https://github.com/Laradock/laradock.git`

2) Creating several project folders

```
- laradock
- new-project
  ﹂index.php
- test-project
  ﹂index.php
```

3) Setting up Nginx config files for each project

`laradock/nginx/sites/new-project.conf`

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name ~^(?<project>.+)\.laradock\.dev$;
    root /var/www/$project;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
...
}
```

And the same config for `laradock/nginx/sites/test-project.conf`

4) Compose

`docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin`

---

As the result Nginx container fails:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                                                                                    NAMES
3189cee03979        laradock_nginx        "/bin/bash /opt/star…"   6 seconds ago       Exited (1) 4 seconds ago                                                                                                            laradock_nginx_1
b078751511b4        laradock_php-fpm      "docker-php-entrypoi…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds               9000/tcp                                                                                                 laradock_php-fpm_1
e4c2eab1cd2b        laradock_phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds               0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp                                                                                     laradock_phpmyadmin_1
d2f5ce2fdda4        laradock_workspace    "/sbin/my_init"          8 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds               0.0.0.0:3000-3001->3000-3001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8001->8000/tcp   laradock_workspace_1
40da6b9cfdd5        laradock_mysql        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds               0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                                                        laradock_mysql_1
7963bf244ca6        docker:19.03-dind     "dockerd-entrypoint.…"   8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds               2375-2376/tcp                                                                                            laradock_docker-in-docker_1
```

But if I remove config file from `nginx/sites` and leave just one of them working i.e. `test-project.conf` it works fine as for one project. I enter `localhost` in address bar and it loads the page correctly just in case if there is one config file in `nginx/sites` but not two of or more.

How to setup Nginx config files properly to handle multiple projects on localhost? Is there any way to hardcode `server_name` value instead of using variable `$project`?

Answer (score 4):

I copied the default.conf file for every new config. In every new created conf file i needed to remove the ssl ipv6only=on part

from this:

```
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
```

to this:

```
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443;
```

I found it out because of this thread on reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/9ubn31/laradock_nginx_issue_for_multi_site_configuration/

Now it works fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: this answer deservers a cookie!